# How to load appsetting.json section into Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Dictionary<int, String>>> in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

in all the projects API I did to inject appsettings I used to

```
services.Configure<Class>(Configuration.GetSetcion("NameSection"))
```

and the section in the set-up was made like this:

```
"NameSection": {
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2"
}
```

Since I now receive a message with three parameters, and depending on these three parameters use a different connection string, I would use these structures:

```
Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Dictionary <int, String>>>
```

Appsetting:

```
"ServiceBus": [
{
  "Device": "Device1",
  "FromInformations": [
    {
      "From": "X",
      "TypeMessages": [
        {
          "EnrichedType": 0,
          "ConnectionString": "link1"
        },
        {
          "EnrichedType": 1,
          "ConnectionString": "link2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

because receiving from the message Device, From and EnrichedType, the connection string is immediate to find. How can I inject these settings?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use IConfiguration??

Comment: @DetectivePikachu I already use it

services.Configure<Class>(configuration.GetSetcion("NameSection"))